# Is pointwise multiple linear regression possible in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, linear-regression, scalar

I am attempting to run a pointwise multiple linear regression in Matlab, i.e., to obtain a regression coefficient for each point in my dataset.

I have three independent variables and one dependent variable. Each variable is a column vector with ~1.6 million records. Each data point represents a geographic location; my point in doing all this is to try and see the effects of the predictor variables on the response variable on a pixel-per-pixel basis.

I have already successfully run fitlm, regress, and mldivide; these functions get me the three regression coefficients for my data. However, I want to run a multiple regression through all my points independently, so that ultimately I will get three columns of regression coefficients of 1.6 million records each.

My data contains some NaN. These rows cannot be ignored; the final column vector must be the same size as the original vectors since the data point's location is related to real-world coordinates.

I've looked into the code for bsxfun but don't believe it can help me. I also tried using dot notation but that didn't work. My thinking now is to create a for loop and use mldivide one row at a time. However, when I tried using 'regress' on scalars (mocking one row of data), I got the error "X is rank deficient to within machine precision." I didn't get this error when I used mldivide.

Is doing a pointwise multiple linear regression even possible? It seems to me that my sample size is way too small. Any feedback on the feasibility of this, and whether a for loop is a good direction to pursue, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In short - it's probably possible (depending on the model you're fitting), `for` is bad here, aim for vectorization. Check out this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190845.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. After thinking about this some more I think the best way to go about this is to create a moving window of ~40 data points each, and then to regress those points. I'm working on that now.